# Why am I getting core.Model.none?

Tags: python, django, model, backend, web-development-server

I'm working on a ***django based backend.***

I have a **Submentor** model. This model is going to have a **list** of **names** associated with it. So, I made a model called **List**. they both have a **manytoMany** relationship. Now, I made another model called **names**. This has a ***ManytoMany*** relationship with **List**. The list will have many names. Each Submentor will have one List each.

After coding when I try to add a value in The list from admin console I get ***core.Name.none*** instead of the name in my Submentors list.

What am I doing wrong?

**code of models :-**

```
class Names(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SAccepted_list(models.Model):
    saccepted_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='saccepted_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.saccepted_name)

class SPending_list(models.Model):
    spending_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='spending_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.spending_name)


class SRejected_list(models.Model):
    srejected_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='srejected_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.srejected_name)


class SubMentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    mentee_pref_count = models.IntegerField(default=3, verbose_name='Preferred mentee count')
    rating = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='Submentor')
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, related_name='subskills')
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True, related_name='subcourses')
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True, related_name='subprojects')
    saccepted_list = models.ManyToManyField(SAccepted_list,blank=True,related_name='saccepted_list')
    spending_list = models.ManyToManyField(SPending_list, blank=True,related_name='spending_list')
    srejected_list = models.ManyToManyField(SRejected_list, blank=True,related_name='srejected_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

    def get_mentee_count(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.trainees.exists():
            return self.trainees.count()
        else:
            return 0

class Accepted_list(models.Model):
    accepted_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='accepted_name')
    # saccepted_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='saccepted_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.accepted_name)

class Pending_list(models.Model):
    pending_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='pending_name')
    # spending_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='spending_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pending_name)


class Rejected_list(models.Model):
    rejected_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='rejected_name')
    # srejected_name = models.ManyToManyField(Names,blank =True, related_name='srejected_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rejected_name)



class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    mentee_pref_count = models.IntegerField(default=5, verbose_name='Preferred menteee count')
    rating = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='mentor')
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, related_name='skills')
    accepted_list = models.ManyToManyField(Accepted_list,blank=True,related_name='accepted_list')
    pending_list = models.ManyToManyField(Pending_list, blank=True,related_name='pending_list')
    rejected_list = models.ManyToManyField(Rejected_list, blank=True,related_name='rejected_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

    def get_mentee_count(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.trainees.exists():
            return self.trainees.count()
        else:
            return 0
```

picture of me adding names direct through admin console:-

[image: See where core.Names.none is written]

Thank you.

Comment: This setup really doesn't make any sense. You're getting that value because your spending_list m2m field points to the SPending_list model, and the only thing on that model is *another* m2m to Names; the `__str__` method on SPending_list uses that m2m to produce the string for display in the select box, but there is nothing selected so all it can do is print "none". But really, having an m2m that points to another m2m is absolutely not what you want to do.

Comment: oh, what should I do then? I've just started learning django and any help is appreciated. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem. It was wrong of me in the first place to use m2m and then another to make a list.
Instead I used only 1 m2m relationship with Lists and then made a property of them to be charfield. Now it's working properly.

Thanks :)